# Create Client of Web Service of C# API

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl

I have created a web service in C# in which I have used a C# entity class that is passed to web service as input by serializing this class and in web service I have deserialize it my web method here is my Serializing code

```
string xmlText;
var msg = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
var ms = new MemoryStream();
using (var xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(ms, Encoding.ASCII) { Formatting = Formatting.Indented })
{
    msg.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, obj);
    ms = (MemoryStream)xmlTextWriter.BaseStream;
    xmlText = new UTF8Encoding().GetString(ms.ToArray());
    ms.Dispose();
}
return xmlText;
```

I get XML of this class and I pass it to my web method and I just deserialize it and use this class.
Now I want to expose this web method to all clients. The client can be Java, PHP or any other programming language. How will I provide this Class to those clients?
I have searched on google there I find create wsdl file. How to convert my entity class to a wsdl file?

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Regards.

Comment: Why serialize it first? You don't need to do that.

Answer (score -1):

I think the best way to go is what you're already doing: serialize your objects into XML or Json and pass these strings to your clients. These clients will then have to recreate the objects back (using specific methods like json_decode for PHP, for example). A WSDL file describes the public methods of a web service. It will help you to create your clients, but it won't help you to serialize and deserialize objects.

Comment: but how Java and PHP clients will get my c# entity class and how will they consume my web service?? should I have to worry about these clients?? Or do I have to create just this class and use it for serializing and deserializing my class?? Is my approach is correct??

Comment: Do I have to create web method with string input and client will send xml as there input?? and do I have to write my xml parser code instead of serializing and deserializing??

Comment: Since the clients don't run on .NET, there is no way to give them .NET objects. Objects most be converted to strings and the clients must build the objects from these strings. The solution I was talking about is this: your webservices send objects converted into XML/JASON strings and all clients receive these strings. They must then recreate the objects from the strings, using some kind of tools (eg XSD.EXE, but this is for .NET) or code (see this for JAVA : http://bit.ly/Mty19R). You should document the XML/JASON your services will provide: some clients may need them to parse the file. Cheers

Comment: SRO I am very new at this I didn't understand what you are trying to say as per my understanding the thing you saying is I have to create web method with sting parameter as input and I have to write xml parser for provided xml and serializing from client and deserializing in web method because it will not work for JAVA users am I correct?? Thanks for your previous reply and future replies ;) :)

Comment: Why would you serialize first? .NET will do that for you, and will create information in the WSDL to tell the clients the type of the data.